# What is this “XX” 開 “#” “上/平/入/去” “XX” method for describing character pronunciation?

Tags: phonology

Here is an incredibly horrible quality excerpt (read: screenshot) from 《四川邛崍油榨方言記》:

[image: hi, guys]

here's the highlights from `2 ər` that I wanted to point out:

> 爾 止開三上紙日
>
> 兒 止開三平支日
>
> 而 止開三平之日
>
> 二 止開三去至日

and for contrast the highlights from `3 i`

> 逼 曾開三入職幚
>
> 彼 止開三上紙幚
>
> 秕 止開三上旨幚
>
> 蔽 蟹開三去祭幚
>
> 箅 曾鼻子蟹開四去霽幚

The last two “XX” might be final + initial - 逼 for instance `職幚` final `i` plus initial `b` -- a backwards 反切 - a 切反, if you will. 反切 usually includes the correct tone with the final, which doesn't seem to be carried out here - 職 would be second-tone, here, if anything - and not first like the tone that is noted for 逼.

上/平/入/去 is, obviously, a tone marker - still not really seeing how the pre-fixed number fits in with it, though.

“X” + 開 I'm more lost on.

Does anyone know what this method is?

How does its components work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these're codified verse, each character represent a "value" of particular "property", [廣韻](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E9%9F%BB) is the origin.

```
逼   曾開三入職幫
```

逼   the character looked up

曾   one of sixteen [韻攝](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%9D)

開   開口音 (開 for 開口音, or 合 for 合口音)

三   等第 (一, 二, 三 or 四)

入   entering tone, 聲調 tones (平, 上, 去 or 入)

職   this one is 韻目 (slightly different from 韻母 finals, there're 206 韻目 in 廣韻

幫   it's 聲母 initials

so, back to your question:

```
“X” + 開
```

it's **[ 通 | 江 | 止 | 遇 | 蟹 | 臻 | 山 | 效 | 果 | 假 | 宕 | 梗 | 曾 | 流 | 深 | 咸 ]** + **[ 開口音 |合口音 ]**

last, it's interesting that the book used traditional chinese script :)

info added.

ok, if you understand cantonese, literary chinese & traditional script, here it's:

## 韻攝

in the rhythm book 廣韻, there're 206 韻目, which was "assimilated" into 16 韻攝, that, ignoring initials, tones; similar finals were grouped together. i guessed it's easier to remember 16, instead of 206 :)

for example:

通攝, which included "東韻", "董韻", "送韻", "屋韻", "冬韻", "宋韻", "沃韻", "鍾韻", "腫韻", "用韻", "燭韻"; in cantonese (sydney lay scheme), these're:

通   tung1,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/tung1.Mp3)

東   dung1,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/dung1.Mp3)

董   dung2,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/dung2.Mp3)

送   sung3,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sung3.Mp3)

屋   uk1,    [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/uk1.Mp3)

冬   dung1,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/dung1.Mp3)

宋   sung3,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/sung3.Mp3)

沃   yuk1,   [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/juk1.Mp3)

鍾   jung1,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zung1.Mp3)

腫   jung2,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zung2.Mp3)

用   yung6,  [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/jung6.Mp3)

燭   juk1,   [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zuk1.Mp3)

grep the idea now?

[漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/), [鉅宋廣韻](https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/pickup/view/category/categoryArchives/0500000000/0511000000/00)

## 等第

this one, it's roughly louder, loud, quiet, quieter (from 1 to 4). it's derived from 韻圖 ([rhyme table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime_table)).

the internet archive has a copy of 韻鏡, in page 100-101:

https://archive.org/details/02077186.cn

[image]

in bottom right, one can find

```
北
◯
逼
◯
```

in which, the 等第 of [北](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8C%97) is **一**, while 等第 of [逼](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%80%BC) is **三**

Comment: I understand the intials, finals, tones, and the 开合 distinction, but what are the 等第 and the 韵攝 for?

Comment: i edited the answer, have a look :)